# Boost::UUIDs - When to use them ?

Tags: boost, uuid

Serializing boost::uuids have a cost. Using them to index into vector / unordered_map requires additional hashing. What are the ideal use cases where boost::uuids are ideal data structures to use ?

Answer (score 0):

UUIDs are valuable if you want IDs that are stable in time and across storage systems.

Imagine having two databases, each with auto-generated IDs.

Merging them would be a headache if the IDs are generated by incrementing integral values from 0.

Merging them would be a breeze if all relevant IDs are UUID.

Likewise, handing out a lot of data to an external party, who records operations offline, and subsequently applying these operations back on original data is much easier with UUIDs - even if relations between elements have been changed, new elements created etc.

UUID is also handy for universal "identification" (**not** authentication/authorization!) - like in driver versions, plugin ids etc. Think about detecting that an MSI is an update to a particular installed software package.

In general, I wouldn't rate UUIDs a characteristic of any data structure. I'd rate it a tool in designing your infrastructure. It plays on the level of persistence, exchange, not so much on the level of algorithms and in-memory manipulation.